# Possible conflict while setting function between JQuery and vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined

I am trying to make my own bootleg bash clone in JS and PHP, but I am stuck on a problem. When trying to execute this script, error log tells me that enteredCommand() is not defined, even though you can see it being above the form.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        if($(".command") !== null){
            function enteredCommand(){
        }
        } else{
            // do nothing
        }
    });
</script>
<form id="commandField" onsubmit="return enteredCommand();">
    <p>bbash~ User:</p>
    <input class="command" type=text>
</form>
```

Please help! I am new. This is not a duplicate, since I don't see how it can't be defined. And yes, the console specifies that the error happens at "onsubmit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've defined the `enteredCommand()` function out of scope of the `onsubmit` invocation.

You need to invert the logic so that the `if` condition is within the `enteredCommand()` function. Also note the use of an unobtrusive event handler in the JS code. Adding `onX` attributes to HTML is no longer good practice and should be avoided.

Finally, to retrieve a value from a jQuery object you need to call `val()`. Comparing a jQuery object to `null` will never be true, as a jQuery object is never null.

```js
let execCommand = c => {
  console.log(`User entered '${c}', handle it here...`);
} 

$(function() {
  let $command = $('.command');

  $('#commandForm').on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission so you can handle it manually
    
    let command = $command.val().trim();
    if (command)
      execCommand(command);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<form id="commandForm">
  <p>bbash~ User:</p>
  <input class="command" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help